# Excel VBA: Copy loop for multiple named ranges

Tags: excel, loops, named-ranges, vba

I want to copy several named ranges. The ranges have a set naming convention with a short string, then number (eg, Body1, Body2, etc).

My workaround loops through each sheet name, and copies range B2:C50  instead of each named range, which is what I`d prefer.

Code:

```
Dim Bnum As Integer          'Bnum is Loop Counter
Dim Nbodies As Integer       'Nbodies is how many loops should go
Dim BodyNum As String

'BodyNum is the sheet name where the named range is (and also the named range I`d like to copy). The named ranges are workbook wide in this case


Nbodies = Range("N.Bodies")  'Called from elsewhere in the workbook

Bnum = 1                    'Initial counter set
BodyNum = "Body" & Bnum     'Name of worksheet+named range which I want to copy

Do Until Bnum = Nbodies + 1
    Workbooks(Wkbk).Activate
    Worksheets(BodyNum).Range("B2:C50").Copy

'Copies range manually definied in vba B2:C50 in this case. Want to copy named range with the same name as Bodynum, varying the digit for each loop

    Workbooks(Inputbk).Activate     'The paste portion works fine
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Call Cursor.Cursor
    Workbooks(Wkbk).Activate
    Bnum = Bnum + 1         'Iterates loop counter
    BodyNum = "Body" & Bnum
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a set of worksheets named "Body1".."BodyN", each having a named range bearing the name of the worksheet itself.

You mention that you `Want to copy named range with the same name as Bodynum`.

Then all you should have to do is turn this line:

```
Worksheets(BodyNum).Range("B2:C50").Copy
```

into this:

```
Worksheets(BodyNum).Range(BodyNum).Copy
```

Comment: It doesn't want to work for calling the named range, although it works fine for the worksheet. I would be able to call a specific named range, using `Worksheets(BodyNum).Range("Body1").Copy` for example, but that doesn't help with respect to the loop

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to copy several named ranges, called Body1, Body2, Body3 etc, each located on a worksheet of the same name to a seperate workbook using a loop. I'd like the named range to be iterated with the loop, instead of currently calling the cells manually. However, using `Worksheets(BodyNum).Range(BodyNum).Copy` results in a debug error and will not run, while calling the cells manually (either `Range("Body1").Copy` or `Range("B2:C50")` would work, but doesn't loop like I'd like it to

Comment: If I remove the Worksheets part of the command, and just call range globally such as `Range(BodyNum).Copy` then the error is instead Method 'Range of object'_Global' failed

Comment: Do you mean that worksheet Body1 contains named range Body1, worksheet Body2 contains named range Body2, etc. or that all named ranges Body1, Body2, etc. are on the same worksheet?

Comment: The first option. There are several worksheets, each with one named range with the same name as the worksheet

Comment: If you use the code provided in my answer, what error number and message do you get? And have you checked that your worksheets each do contain a range named the same as themselves?

Comment: Ahh. I had an extra period in the named ranges, so the VBA couldn't call it. Well... now I feel silly.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool! The best way to thank people here is to upvote helpful answers and mark the best one using the big green check mark.